# Find solution of x1+x2+x3(x4+x5) without using BruteForceSearch

Tags: algorithm, integer, linear-regression

Hi i have a optimization question, for example

I need to minimize the function

```
minimize x1+x2+x3(x4+x5)
```

And the requirement is

```
60/x1+ 30/x2+ 6/x3 * [80/x4 + 150/x5] < 750
x1+x2+x3(x4+x5) < 7
```

x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 are integers and greater than 0

How to find the solution of x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 ?

Is there any optimized method instead of BruteForceSearch ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us the question exactly as it was given to you?

Comment: Please add updates, clarifications and corrections to the question itself using [edit].

Comment: A brute-force approach here will not involve too many possibilities to check....

Comment: With these constraints, there is no solution. Sorry, I don't have an algorithm but I can share how I reached the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Under the constraints above, and noting that x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 are integers and greater than 0, A solution does not exist.

A general form of solving this kind of optimization problems (minimizing a function subject to a constraint) can be done using Lagrange multipliers. [Read more on Lagrange multipliers here][1].

In your problem, the Lagrange multiplier will take the form of

```
L(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,lambda) =  1/(x1+x2+x3(x4+x5)) - lambda * (60/x1+ 30/x2+ 6/x3 * [80/x4 + 150/x5] - 750)
```

Note that the Lagrange multipliers method is used to maximize a function, therefore, the original function to maximize was set to the power of `-1`, making it a maximization problem.

Taking the partial derivative of the Lagrange multiplier `L(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,lambda)` w.r.t each of the 6 variables and trying to zero out the gradient will result in 6 equations with 6 variables, which can be solved to find a general solution (a solution will not be found in this specific problem though)

[1]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:~:text=In%20mathematical%20optimization%2C%20the%20method,chosen%20values%20of%20the%20variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20optimization%2C%20the%20method,chosen%20values%20of%20the%20variables)).

Comment: Thank you sir, I use scipy.optimize package to solve it.